# Dynamic table for Insert Syntax SQL - Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax

I would like to have the SQL SYNTAX INSERT code to be dynamic for which table to insert data into. When I try the code below I get SYNTAX error, probably due to that it adds '-marks around the table. How can I solve this?

```
system=str(event['system'])
value1=str(event['value1'])
value2=str(event['value2'])
timestamp=str(event['timestamp'])
table=str('table1')    

insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO %s (system, value1, value2, timestamp) ""VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
data = (table, system, value1, value2, timestamp)
cur.execute(insert_stmt, data)
conn.commit()
```

My Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table1' (system, value1, value2, timestamp) VALUES ('qwerty', '1', '1',' at line 1\")", "errorType": "ProgrammingError",

Answer (score 0):

You use reserved keywords as fieldname timestamp. You can only use it if you
put it in backticks like:

```
 insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO %s (system, value1, value2, `timestamp`) ""VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
data = (table, system, value1, value2, timestamp)
```

But make your live easier! Dont use KEYWORDS as fieldname !!!

Comment: Thank you! That is a good valid point. I will change that.
But I dont' think that's the cause for my error.

Comment: if it not or not only your error. please output the generated query and post it